# How to click on a class with a dynamic variable

Tags: java, selenium, web, automation, driver

I like to be able to search and click by cluster-id-hash="foobar", but I'm unable too. It can't find the element

Here are some examples of the css on the page

```
<div class="ancCol w33 person-panel" _ngcontent-c6="" cluster-id-hash="KYDQEX8il7BIG2"></div>

or
<div class="ancCol w33 person-panel annColRow" _ngcontent-c6="" cluster-id-hash="5gamjajdkjgPcma">
```

I've tried this where clusterIdHash is a string that I pass:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".cluster-id-hash='" + clusterIdHash )).click();
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[cluster-id-hash='" + clusterIDHash + "']")).click();
```